# Cannot follow links to SO posts from MSO questions because the SO posts have been deleted

Tags: discussion, questions

Seems like more times than not, when I click on a link to a question (or answer) on MSO, the link goes to the happy "This question has been removed" page. For those of us with less than 10k reputation who didn't see the topic immediately, this makes it very hard to understand the context of said questions. This is because we don't have sufficient privileges to view deleted content.

Example: the first link in [How could I have dealt better with this "too broad" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253839/1454117)

Another problem is that less-than-optimal questions that under discussion tend to be cleaned up (either as a result of the discussion, or just because it was less-than-optimal to begin with). Again, those reading the MSO conversation after the update has been made are left without a clear context for the discussion.

What, if anything, can be done to help alleviate this pain point?

Comment: Earn another 7,720 reputation.  Or win a moderator election.

Comment: You could try in a chatroom if a 10K-er wants to post a screenshot...

Comment: I find that in the majority of cases discussion a deleted post it's not actually necessary to go to the deleted post to meaningfully discuss it.  There are exceptions, but they are the exceptional cases, not the standard cases.  Of the remaining exceptional cases where seeing the exact details is particularly relevant, a comment requesting someone to edit a quote of the post into the meta-discussion resolves the problem nicely.

Comment: Your second part is covered by the edit history on every post. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mat Most links don't indicate which revision.

Comment: @Servy I like the suggestion of requesting an edit with a quote.

Comment: [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773) -- _Increase of voting activities observed in main site posts that have been exposed at meta. Most ironic when someone complaining to Meta about "unfair downvotes" on another site gets more downvotes. Also seen: closing, re-opening, deleting etc..._

Comment: @LeviStanley As I said, usually this is not needed.  Generally sufficient context can be given without needing a full quote, however if it's clear that there's no possible way to answer the question without a quote of the content, then feel free to ask for one.  Just don't go around asking for it on every single meta question discussing a post, because they're just not always needed.

Comment: @Servy Right, if it's not needed for context then it's not needed for context. Care to write up an answer? You provided a lot of excellent information in these comments.

Comment: @oberlies he is talking about deleted questions/answers. They are only visible to people with more than 10K rep points

Comment: @oberlies I updated the question to be more clear and added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that in the majority of cases discussion a deleted post it's not actually necessary to go to the deleted post to meaningfully discuss it. There are exceptions, but they are the exceptional cases, not the standard cases.

Of the remaining exceptional cases where seeing the exact details is particularly relevant, a comment requesting someone to edit a quote of the post into the meta-discussion resolves the problem nicely.  Be careful here, and don't go around asking for a quote on every single discussion of a deleted post, because so many questions just don't require it.  If, after reading through a question, you're really struggling to figure out what's going on at all, then asking for the additional context helps to improve that question.

Comment: +1 also there are some cached versions available most of the time..